# Azure B2C integration with sql server authorization scheme and unique validation - do I use Identity Experience Framework?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need help determining how to integrate the Azure B2C authentication with the authorization within my app. I got the susi (sign up sign in) user flow working, but I need to do two things. First, I need to validate the alias to ensure no other such alias already exists and I need to add the user to my sql server database to ensure they are available for authorization processes (eg: users can allow other users to view/edit their resources).

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4URCwM0Eiuk), which seems to cover what I want to do, but I think I could use some explanation. [This article](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-With-External-Authorization-Store/) also seems to come close, but it is returning keys from a database as opposed to inserting into a database. That seems like minor change.

It seems like I need to replace the susi user flow with a B2C Identity Experience Framework policy, but I still want the other steps to be completed. I think I should download the susi policy and edit it and upload it to the IEF, but I am not sure.

I previously was trying to capture the events in a web app in the Startup.cs file when configuring the service during the OnTicketReceived event, [like this](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/azure-ad-b2c-onticketreceived-newuser-claim/), but this didn't cover mobile apps, so I think the IEF solves for this by including the steps in the flow.

I just want to confirm this is the right way to accomplish what I am looking to accomplish and seeing if anybody has any step by step examples.

It seems like it would be a good tutorial to show starting with a working susi user flow and editing it to add integration with an Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

Using IEF by calling the REST API will be the right way to accomplish your requirement. During the signup process, execute a restful technical profile which will call an REST API service there you can validate the user existance in your local DB and create the user in the database and proceed the registration process in B2C tenant.

Another approach would be after signing up the user can be created by the service and for the first call, service can insert a claim for itself with new database user Id.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac) showing how to implement RBAC in B2C using security groups. If the role model is very simple, you could also consider attaching them directly to the user object as custom claim.

Comment: Ragha, I am looking at the sample. How other than IEF can the user be created in the database, unless I replicate the code for each app (Web, Android, iOS)?

Comment: @Icj: I don't see any other way to create a user in database other than IEF.